# How to create a button to generates a text list of all emails from a related object

Tags: soql, email, custom-object, custom-button, mail-chimp

Very new to Salesforce but not new to SQL guy here. I'm just wondering what method I could use to create a button in a custom object that would query a junction object for the other related object's email fields, then format them into a nice text list.

My schema is like this http://puu.sh/sNqAN/7240986c30.png. I want to be able to hit a button called "Make email list" or something in the tab of any given Interest Group, and be able to have that instance query all its junction objects for the emails in their contact fields, then return the result and do something with it. My general need is to either create a mailing list that can be fed into MailChimp (the current mailing software that the nonprofit I'm working for are using) or otherwise produce a result that the staff could use to help organize their mass emails. The company does have MailChimp integrated into Salesforce at least partially, so if there's a way to just go directly from "Button Press -> (bunch of scripting and queries) -> Mailchimp List" that would be absolutely fantastic.

Any help would be great, and thanks in advace.

Comment: You have two options -- let the server do the work and integrate Mailchimp from the controller - or let Javascript do the work by making queries on database and taking results and integrating with Mailchimp.  You'll need to expose more about how you plan on passing lists to Mailchimp given Mailchimps APIs

Comment: I honestly have no idea how their API works or anything, I've just been dumped into this and am trying my best to figure out how to do what they want without making the system overly complex. After further examination it seems like I can probably just use a custom field in Contacts to enable MC to create these lists, but since it's not fully set up and I can't really proceed without consulting the company I guess I'm locked up a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used visual workflow to output a list of e-mails

Lookup the matching records, and add to sObject collection.

Loop through the collection, and add the value of the current record to a text variable and then add a br()

Then display the text variable in a screen element.

Should work for list up to ~1000 records, depending on how you build it.

I have not worked closely w the mail chimp connector but I believe it works off campaigns so if you are working with standard contacts and leads as your subscribers, it might be easier to use reports to add the correct records to campaigns.

Comment: I just tried this and for some reason SF doesn't want me to be able to use Contact__c.Email as a field of Interest__c ? Maybe I'm just being dense here, but is there a way I can just use raw SOQL in the Flow Designer?

Comment: What is interest__c?   No you can't use soql in flows, have to suffer through the 1998 flash player magic

Comment: Just put a bullet in me, I don't want to suffer anymore. EDIT: Also whoops no multilines. I want to do something like "SELECT Interests__c.Contact__c.Email from Interests__c WHERE Interests__c.InterestGroup__c.Name == {an input}" (I assume it would look like this) but you'd think I was trying to make a square circle or something. It would be a lot easier if I could just manually join everything.

Comment: Oh, also it seems I forgot, the objects I'm working with are Contacts, InterestGroup__c and Interest__c (a junction), and Interest__c is a child in a M-D relationship of both of the others. It's in the image I linked.

Comment: You can do [cross object field reference in flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_crossobject_reference.htm), so if you did a fast lookup on a interest object, and included the contact__c relationship in the sObject variable/collection, you can traverse to pull in the contact email.   You might run into issues because you cant filter a query based on a list of IDs, ie lookup list of interest groups where name = x, and then lookup the interest__c records (to get contact email) for those interest groups.

Comment: So I've been trying to do that but the app crashes and I honestly don't know if I can access the logs anywhere. I've got a FastLookUp that gets all the interests (since I need to check every single one of them due to not being able to join) and stores their InterestGroup__c and Contact__c fields, then I have a loop that assigns every element in that collection to an SObject. Then there's a decision that needs to be checking if {!interests.InterestGroup__c.Name) == {!Interest_Group_name}, but the designer will only allow me to do {!interests.Name} because I can seemingly only access ...

Comment: ... fields from an Interest__c, not from its children. I really feel like there should be a better way to stick everything together through a junction object but every time I try to do ANYTHING that makes a bit of sense the designer blocks me.

Comment: You might be able to create formula fields on the junction object to pull in the values you want to filter on.  That's prob your best bet.  Flows are not friendly, and debugging is frustrating on a good day.  They can be awesome, but if you can code... maybe better.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea, I'll try it out later. I'm finished up my hours for the day. Thanks for your help. Hopefully once the frustration wears off I can figure out how to get this thing working.